# ASMX web service hide parameter given

Tags: c#, web-services

Hello I have a web service asmx that takes in one parameter here it is below:

```
public void HelloWorld(string secret)
{
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(encoding.GetBytes(secret));
}
```

My question is...is it possible that the string typed at the time of entering in the string "secret" that the text gets hidden...I know its going to just display it once I hit invoke but I'm just trying to play around and see if its possible to accomplish this.

In a windows form there is a Password Char property that will hide the text you enter and just place a "*" for example.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The best way which I have used it is to secure your string (Password) is to use encryption with SSL. Please have look below link for more info.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996415.aspx